# How to edit the size of a web part in a modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

Am using a modern communication site,and i added some web part but cant seem to find a way to edit those web part sizes.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I have found up to now is to change the number of columns in the section. Basically, placing the web part into a section with one, two or three columns will reformat and change the way it looks. Automatically, so you don't have much control unfortunately.